# Does the IIS "Modifying HTTP Response Headers" tutorial use the wrong variable?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to work through the IIS tutorial "Modifying HTTP Response Headers" to replace my location headers. 
https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/modifying-http-response-headers

I am quite fresh when it comes to IIS, however, it seems to me that they start by creating a server variable called "ORIGINAL_HOST", but later in the tutorial, start using "ORIGINAL_URL".

So is something funky happening that I dont know about, or should "ORIGINAL_URL" really be "ORIGINAL_HOST"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that they did mess up and that it should be "ORIGINAL_HOST" instead of "ORIGINAL_URL". If you look at the images they have after they start referring to it as "ORIGINAL_URL" you will see that it says "ORIGINAL_HOST" with the Pattern that they said to add for "ORIGINAL_URL".

I don't have enough rep points to comment on your question or else I would have done so.